How to use a private property within a static method in javascript?
I'm trying the following but the editor marks it as an error
class ColorPicker {
  #colors = [array of rgb colors]
  ...
  ...

  constructor(color) {
    ...
  }

  static get random() {
    return this.#colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.#colors.length)]
  }
}

I would like to be able to obtain a color from the ColorPicker class without having to instantiate it to be able to configure other objects with some of the colors that ColorPicker handles but also to be able to instantiate it since it is a component, for example
this.#color = ColorPicker.random

this.#colorpicker = new ColorPicker(this.#color)

I have a Line object that has this property but also instantiates a ColorPicker object so I can manipulate the color of the line later with this component
The solution for the moment is the following
  static get random() {
    const colors = [Array of rgb colors] //

    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  }

But I would like to know why I can't directly use the private property #colors
Get an answer to solve my problem

Your private field is an instance private field. It doesn't exist without an instance (object) of the class. Did you mean to create a static private field? If so, just add static in front of it. If not, where is random supposed to get the value from? (Should random be not static?)

(For the avoidance of doubt, because this is a slightly unusual thing about JavaScript: this in a static method is not an instance of the class [unless you do something unusual to make it one], it's the class constructor function that you're calling the method on [for instance, if you do ColorPicker.random(), this is the ColorPicker function].)

Based on your description, you want a static private field rather than the instance private field you currently have. An instance private field exists on instances of the class, so if you don't have an instance, it doesn't exist. A static private field exists on the class constructor itself (which is what this is when you use ColorPicker.random). To make #colors a static private field, add static in front of it, so you can access it from a static method/accessor like your random getter.
Here's an example:


class ColorPicker {
    static #colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"/*...*/];
    // ...
    // ...

    constructor(color) {
        // In a comment you mentioned needing access to #colors here,
        // though you didn't give an example or reason.
        // You can use it via `ColorPicker.#colors` or
        // `this.constructor.#colors`:
        console.log(`# of colors: ${ColorPicker.#colors.length}`);
        console.log(`# of colors: ${this.constructor.#colors.length}`);
    }

    static get random() {
        return this.#colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.#colors.length)];
    }
}

const color = ColorPicker.random;
console.log(color);

// Creating an instance so we can see access within the constructor
new ColorPicker("red");



(I've used strings there as stand-ins for the colors, but that's not important.)

Side note: If ColorPIcker is in a JavaScript module and you export it, you could make colors a module-level global rather than a static private field. A module-level global is private to the module (if you don't export it), but accessible to all code within the module. But it's largely a matter of style.


// NOTE: Assumes this is code in a JavaScript module
const colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"/*...*/];

class ColorPicker {
    // ...
    // ...

    constructor(color) {
        // Of course, `colors` is also accessible here
        console.log(`# of colors: ${colors.length}`);
    }

    static get random() {
        return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    }
}

const color = ColorPicker.random;
console.log(color);

// Creating an instance so we can see access within the constructor
new ColorPicker("red");




Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work at all since the first case generates an error when trying to use this.#colors inside the class in non-static getter's, and for the second solution, what I'm really looking for is that the colors array is not accessible, which is why #colors is private.

@Ezio - The question doesn't show the constructor using #colors anywhere. If you need to use #colors within the constructor or an instance method or accessor, access it via ColorPicker.#colors or this.constructor.#colors. Also, again, if you use a module, colors (even outside ColorPicker) is private (to the code in that module, which could just be ColorPicker if you want), as I described above.
